# Audi A6 C6 on board computer is off

Tags: electrical, audi, instrument-cluster

I'm not sure if it's something wrong with on-board computer or I just don't know how to turn it on. When the car is started the display is completely off. and only turns on sometimes when some kind of "service" message appears. From then it's working fine.

If it's normal behavior? How do I turn it on manually?

Comment: Most likely something is wrong with the display and not the computer. There is probably a service message being displayed all the time and when the display happens to come on it seems like it turned on due to a service message.

Comment: I've read that some people have some problems with on board computer after battery change. Wondering if that could cause that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked with 'Car Gurus' and something as simple as changing the battery or if the battery dies, requires a trip to the dealership to get your system rebooted.

Here is a link to a .pdf for your owners manual:  https://exverkickzber.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/audi-a6-c6-owners-manual-pdf.pdf

While there is a reset switch shown for resetting different functions on a working computer, a non-working computer requires dealer reset.

Good luck.  :)

Comment: Nowadays most of the cars require reset of the car computer after every service. This can be done easily with the help of the OBD dongle or simply removing both the battery terminals and keep is shot for a few minutes and reconnect the battery. The car computer will be reset and ready for use.